# Google cloud function fails when using OpenAI

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-functions, openai-api

I've been strugling with this for a while now.

I just want to create a cloud function that uses the OpenAI package to create a completion. It works fine in my machine but, the second I try to deploy it with `firebase deploy` a healthcheck fails.

This is my code:

```
/**
 * Import function triggers from their respective submodules:
 *
 * import {onCall} from "firebase-functions/v2/https";
 * import {onDocumentWritten} from "firebase-functions/v2/firestore";
 *
 * See a full list of supported triggers at https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions
 */

import { onRequest } from "firebase-functions/v2/https";
import * as logger from "firebase-functions/logger";
import { ChatCompletionRequestMessage, Configuration, OpenAIApi } from "openai";

// Start writing functions
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/typescript

const createAiStuff = async (options?: Params): Promise<any> => {

  try {
    const configuration = new Configuration({
      apiKey: "api-key",
    });

    const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration); // NOTE: If I remove this it works :S
    const completion = await openai.createChatCompletion(...);

    const res = JSON.parse(
      completion?.data.choices[0].message?.content || ""
    );
    
    return res;
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("ERROR", e);
    throw e;
  }
};

export const hello = onRequest(async (request, response) => {
  logger.info("logs!", { structuredData: true });

  try {
    const res = await createAiStuff();
    response.json(res);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    response.send("ERROR from Firebase!");
  }
});
```

I don't get why doing const `openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);` makes the healthchecks fail and how to fix it.

This is the error I'm getting:

> updating Node.js 18 (2nd Gen) function story(us-central1)... Could not
> create or update Cloud Run service story, Container Healthcheck
> failed. Revision 'story-00028-xeb' is not ready and cannot serve
> traffic. The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the
> port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable. Logs for
> this revision might contain more information.